# "Brick Mansions" Movie Dialog

Tags: dialogue, cinema

In the script of the movie, it is written "your backing" but I cannot hear that! I hear this: "your back". What is that in fact?

The passage of dialog:
"Now, with your cooperation and your backing,
we can restore Detroit to its former glory."

The link to the mentioned section of the movie:
https://youtu.be/fhBZ-Tt57Ig?t=101

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about identifying whether a word in a particular bit of dialogue sounds like one word ("backing") or another word ("back"). This is not centrally a matter of grammar or usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your speaker does say **backing** but swallows the end of the word!

Remember that Americans often pronounce Rockin' and a Rollin' without the ending 'g'. Brits in popular culture also do it. Elton John did it everywhere, for example in [Your Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l13iWvcCuwI+) as **this feelin' inside**. Also, the Rolling Stones [Miss You](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hic-dnps6MU) at 1:20 for "Puerto Rican girls just dyin' to meet you", (pronounced **DAHN**-ta MEETCH-ya).

So in your film, the speaker drops even more, but he does have a syllable there (more like "BACK-uh").

Since **backing** is money to back up project plans, a native listener fills in the logical word. You will too.